# Scan sg350-28 with Nessus Credentialed checks

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, cisco, nessus

I have 4 SG350 (SG350-28 28-Port Gigabit Managed Switch) switches

I need to be able to do a Credentialed scans to the switches

The problem is when I try to scan it will not connect to port 22, from the log output it does not look like it is even trying.

SSH is enabled

I can SSH from putty

I can SSH into the switch from the server where nessus is installed

I can also SSH into the switch from other devices such as routers.

I have checked and nessus will do a Credentialed scan against other ssh devices, (RHEL 7)

Any idea why this is not working?

The user I am using is setup as level 15

username aftest

password Test1234 (really simple)

I created a user that can only log in via key, same thing.

I also created a user level 1 and set the enable password.

I have followed the Nessus article

https://community.tenable.com/s/article/Authentication-Requirements-for-Credentialed-Cisco-Scans

I have debugging turned on with the Nessus scanner.

```
Protocol : SSH Port : 22 Failure details :

User : aftest

Plugin : netstat_portscan.nasl Plugin ID : 14272 Plugin Name : Netstat Portscanner (SSH) Message : ssh_recv failed in ssh_kex2.

Plugin : ssh_get_info.nasl Plugin ID : 12634 Plugin Name : Authenticated Check : OS Name and Installed Package Enumeration Message : ssh_recv failed in ssh_kex2. "
```

Couple of things I have noticed.

```
[2022-02-15 21:11:07] SSH Settings Plugin Loaded
[2022-02-15 21:11:07] SSH Settings Initializing : 
  Client Verison:OpenSSH_5.0
  Port:22
  Least Priv:no
  Auto-accept disclaimers:1
[2022-02-15 21:11:07] SSH Settings Credential Loop 0
[2022-02-15 21:11:07] Password Type :password
[2022-02-15 21:11:07] SSH Settings : 
  credential type:password
  username:aftest
  elevate user:root
  elevate with:Cisco 'enable'
[2022-02-15 21:11:07] SSH Settings Credential Loop 1
[2022-02-15 21:11:07] SSH Settings Credential Loop 2
[2022-02-15 21:11:07] SSH Settings Credential Loop 3
[2022-02-15 21:11:07] SSH Settings Credential Loop 4
[2022-02-15 21:11:07] SSH Settings Credential Loop 5
[2022-02-15 21:11:07] SSH Settings Credential Loop 6
```

elevate user:root, why is it trying to elevate as root

Second thing I noticed:

```
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 0] session.set_debug: Debugging enabled at level DEBUG3
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 0] ssh_client_state.set: ** Entering STATE SOC_CLOSED **
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 0] try_ssh_kb_settings_login: Attempting to log in on port 22.
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 0] try_ssh_kb_settings_login: Creating new temporary session to test 'none' authentication.
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] session.set_debug: Debugging enabled at level DEBUG3
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] ssh_client_state.set: ** Entering STATE SOC_CLOSED **
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] try_ssh_kb_settings_login: Opening a connection to port 22 to test 'none' authentication...
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] session.open_connection: Connecting to port 22.
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] session.open_connection: Socket opened on port 22.
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] ssh_client_state.set: ** Entering STATE SOC_OPENED **
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] session.open_connection: Received server version SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3p1.RL
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] session.sshsend: Outgoing Unencrypted packet:

0x00:  53 53 48 2D 32 2E 30 2D 4F 70 65 6E 53 53 48 5F    SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_
0x10:  35 2E 30 0A                                        5.0.            
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] try_ssh_kb_settings_login: Successfully opened a connection on port 22.
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] session.complete_kex: KEX is not yet complete. Attempting to complete KEX before continuing.
[2022-02-15 21:11:58] [session 1] session.sshrecv: Incoming Unencrypted packet:
0x00:  00 00 00 34 07 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 1F 69 64    ...4..........id
0x10:  6C 65 20 63 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 20 74 69    le connection ti
0x20:  6D 65 6F 75 74 20 65 78 70 69 72 65 64 00 00 00    meout expired...
0x30:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                            ........        
[2022-02-15 21:11:58] [session 1] session.sshrecv_until: Handling packet.type: 1 [PROTO_SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT]
[2022-02-15 21:11:58] [session 1] client_cb_msg_disconnect: Entering handler.
[2022-02-15 21:11:58] [session 1] ssh_client_state.set: ** Entering STATE SOC_CLOSED **
[2022-02-15 21:11:58] [session 1] session.close_socket: Closing socket.
[2022-02-15 21:11:58] [session 1] session.set_error: KEX failed: 
[2022-02-15 21:11:58] [session 1] try_ssh_kb_settings_login: Error calling complete_kex().
[2022-02-15 21:11:58] [session 0] Login via sshlib::try_ssh_kb_settings_login has failed.
[2022-02-15 21:11:58] [session 0] session.close_connection: Socket is already closed.
```

If that means what I think it means the idle connection timeout expired but I have the idle timeout set to Never, I also set the idle timeout to 30 to see if that makes a difference.

[image]

```
[root@localhost ~]# ssh -vv aftest@192.168.1.254
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.1.254" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.254 [192.168.1.254] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.3p1.RL
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.3p1.RL pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.254:22 as 'aftest'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1004/2048
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:gKvy1VIaUuuof58/pXPIki3lG5uhIxLBewVAL9oWS0s
debug1: Host '192.168.1.254' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1054/2048
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password

aftest@192.168.1.254's password:

debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.254 ([192.168.1.254]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0




switch778de9#
```

Comment: did you turn on plugin 19506 ?

Comment: @schroeder Yes all plugins are enabled.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe that's running on "legacy" SSH and you need compat SSH for it?

Comment: @SirMuffington how will i know? It should be in the output above however not sure how to tell nessus to use the different ssh version

Comment: @JamesConnigan possibly `tcpdump` on the server and check the handshake?